# Is this interpretation of Stieltjes integration correct?

Tags: real-analysis, intuition

If $f$ is a positive function, the intuitive interpretation of the Riemann integral

$\int_a^b f(x) dx$

is the area under the curve $f$ between $a$ and $b$.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are smooth positive functions. Is it correct to interpret the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

$\int_a^b f(x) d g(x)$ as the volume under a "ribbon", where the height of the ribbon at a point $u$ between $a$ and $b$ is determined by $f$ and the thickness is determined by $g'$?

Comment: It can't be volume, $f(x)$ and $\mathrm{d}g(x)$ are supposed to have the same dimensions of "length" and area units are the square of length units.

Comment: That's not quite satisfying as an answer- we have a limiting sum of the form ∑f(xi)(g(xi+1)−g(xi))\sum f(x_i)(g(x_{i+1}) - g(x_i)), which is a sum of square length units. Even if this weren't the case, the integral as defined above is dimensionless.

Comment: Sorry, latex derp. That should read $\sum f(x_i)(g(x_{i+1}) - g(x_i))$

Comment: @J.M.: The dimensional analysis works out because the thickness of the "ribbon" is $dg/dx$, which is dimensionless.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively replacing $\int_a^b f(x) dg(x)$ with $\int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx$. [A quick trip to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral) reveals that this is perfectly fine when $g$ is absolutely continuous, or when it has a continuous derivative, but may not be valid otherwise:

> If $g$ should happen to be everywhere differentiable, then the integral may still be different from the Riemann integral
>
>     $$\int_a^b f(x) g'(x) \, dx,$$
>
> for example, if the derivative is unbounded. But if the derivative is continuous, they will be the same. This condition is also satisfied if $g$ is the (Lebesgue) integral of its derivative; in this case $g$ is said to be absolutely continuous.
>
> However, $g$ may have jump discontinuities, or may have derivative zero almost everywhere while still being continuous and increasing (for example, $g$ could be the Cantor function), in either of which cases the Riemann–Stieltjes integral is not captured by any expression involving derivatives of $g$.

*Edit:* I didn't notice the word "smooth" in your question. In this light, the answer to your question is yes.

Also, [MathWorld is probably a better reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesIntegral.html): the two expressions are equal "if $f$ is continuous and $g'$ is Riemann integrable over the specified interval".